# How to Stack Divs on top of each other

Tags: html, css

I have a quick rookie-like question. I used to know CSS, but didn't after having not used it in years.....

Anyway,

I'm trying to stack two divs on top of each other. A portion of my code is below.

**CSS:**

```
.faq_left {
    width: 134px;
    height: 495px;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}

.faq_box_top {
    width: 279px;
    height: 200px;
    float: top;
    background-color:black;
}

.faq_box_bottom {
    width: 279px;
    height: 295px;
    float: bottom;
    background-color:green;
}

.faq_right {
    width:783px;
    height: 495px;
    float: left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="faq_left"></div>
<div class="faq_box_top"></div>
<div class="faq_box_bottom"></div>
<div class="faq_right"></div>
```

I would like faq_left on the left.

I would like faq_box_top & faq_box_bottom to be in the center, where faq_box_top is above faq_box_bottom.

I would like faq_right on the right.

Attached is my page and style sheet along with an image of what I am trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please add a [jsfiddle](http://www,jsfiddle.net) so we can see what the code does at this moment, and from there, work towards an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use absolute positioning since it may easily break your layout. Instead I would wrap the top and bottom divs inside another div, like this:

```
<div class="faq_left"></div>
<div class="faq_middle">
    <div class="faq_box_top"></div>
    <div class="faq_box_bottom"></div>
</div>
<div class="faq_right"></div>
```

And then just change the CSS a little bit:

```
.faq_left {
    width: 134px;
    height: 495px;
    float: left;
    background-color:red;
}

.faq_middle {
    width: 279px;
    float: left;
}

.faq_box_top {
    height: 200px;
    background-color:black;
}

.faq_box_bottom {
    height: 295px;
    background-color:green;
}

.faq_right {
    width:134px;
    height: 495px;
    float: left;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

You can see it running here: https://jsfiddle.net/u83dpf7t/

Answer (score 3):

You should use `position` instead of `float` as the values you have given is wrong. My way is, to position them in top, left, bottom and right, with adjusting according to the left or top `50%` by giving the offset in negative margins.

Have a look at the below snippet.

```css
.faq_left,
.faq_box_top,
.faq_box_bottom,
.faq_right {
  position: absolute;
}

.faq_left {
  width: 134px;
  height: 495px;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -247px;
  background-color:red;
}

.faq_box_top {
  width: 279px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -139px;
  background-color:black;
}

.faq_box_bottom {
  width: 279px;
  height: 295px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -139px;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color:green;
}

.faq_right {
  width:783px;
  height: 495px;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -247px;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq_left"></div>
<div class="faq_box_top"></div>
<div class="faq_box_bottom"></div>
<div class="faq_right"></div>
```

This is how it looks in `33%` zoom:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

View the snippet in Full Page.

`float` is only: `left`, `right`, or `none`. There isn't a: <del>`top`</del> or <del>`bottom`</del>.

Right and left boxes have `display: inline-block` so that they sit next to each other.

Top and bottom boxes have `clear: both` so that there is nothing sitting next to them.

Top and bottom boxes have `margin: 0 auto` so that they are centered.

```css
.faq_left {
  width: 134px;
  height: 495px;
  float: left;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.faq_box_top {
  width: 279px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.faq_box_bottom {
  width: 279px;
  height: 295px;
  background-color: green;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.faq_right {
  width: 783px;
  height: 495px;
  float: left;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>33180711</title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="faq_box_top"></div>
  <div class="faq_left"></div>
  <div class="faq_right"></div>
  <div class="faq_box_bottom"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The dimensions of the boxes are odd... is this intentional? It's unclear what you wanted with the left and right boxes...did you want them touching or did you want a space between them? If you desire the latter then change the right box to `float: right`

Answer (score 0):

two changes:

```
.faq_right {
    width:783px;
    height: 495px;
    float: right;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

That should be `right` instead of left, well?

and re-order:

```
<div class="faq_left"></div>

<div class="faq_right"></div>

<div class="faq_box_top"></div>
<div class="faq_box_bottom"></div>
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/pt8dcc1t/1/